# Can't get DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY form RawContacts

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts

Strangely, I can't access `DISPLAY_NAME` nor `DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY` for `RawContacts`:

```
           //Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.CONTENT_URI;
            uri.getBooleanQueryParameter(ContactsContract.Data.VISIBLE_CONTACTS_ONLY, true); //not sure if that works

            String[] mProjection = {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                    //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, //not working
                    //ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, //not working
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DELETED
            };

            String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND "
                    + ContactsContract.Data.DELETED + " = ?";
            String[] args = {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, "0"
            };

            Cursor phones = getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, mProjection, selection, args, null);
```

error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column display_name
```